# Автоматическое создание директорий Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Изучаю Ubuntu.

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю , что папка /etc/tmpfiles.d необходима для выполнения команд, указанных в *.conf файлах, при загрузке системы? Например, если создам файл /etc/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf со следующим содержимом: d /var/run/postgresql postgres postgres - , то при загрузке системы будет создаваться папка  /var/run/postgresql? Если нет, то как это сделать?
2. Возможно ли указать в одном месте пути переменной PATН, чтобы они были видны у каждого пользователя (чтобы не писать export PATH... в bash.bashrc для каждого пользователя)? Указал в /etc/environment пути для PATH, однако они отсутствуют в переменной PATH root пользователя?

PS Ubuntu WSL2 windows 10

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: 1) https://losst.ru/kak-dobavit-skript-v-avtozagruzku-ubuntu Настройте один раз через systemd. На сколько знаю, в отличии от windows, нельзя просто поместить файл в директорию автозапуска для его совершения, нужен сервис. Не могу точно утверждать, но судя по названию "/etc/tmpfiles.d" это директория с временными файлами. для создания директории - dir

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)